# How to use tf-coreml correctly?

Tags: tensorflow, coreml, generative-adversarial-network

I would like to convert a tensorflow model (https://github.com/vanhuyz/CycleGAN-TensorFlow) into a coreml model, to be able to import it on iOS.

I know that to execute the conversion it is sufficient to use this piece of code:

```
import tfcoreml as tf_converter

tf_converter.convert(tf_model_path = 'my_model.pb', 
                     mlmodel_path = 'my_model.mlmodel', 
                     output_feature_names = ['softmax:0'])
```

But I have no idea what to put in the third parameter "output_feature_names". Some idea?

Answer (score 3):

If you open the .pb file with [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron) and scroll all the way to the bottom, you'll see that the last layer is EncodeJpeg, and so the output feature name would be `EncodeJpeg:0`.

However, Core ML does not have an "encode jpeg" operation, so you can't convert the entire graph. You'll need to find the last tensor that Core ML still supports.

I would try `output_feature_names=["G_7/output/Tanh:0"]` but it's quite possible that there are other things in the graph that can't be converted.

Comment: ValueError: Graph has cycles.

Comment: That means you can't convert this model to Core ML 2. However, Core ML 3 will have support for this stuff, so you can try using coremltools 3.0 (currently still in beta).

Comment: Any ideas on how to do or what tool to look for?

Comment: See the documentation of https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml -- it explains how to install the beta versions.